# How do I end my program using a bool (or something else like an if-statement) without using exit(), return 0 or break?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm making a game where you have 21 matches and two players. A player can pick one to three matches and the amount of total matches goes down. However when there is one match left the other player loses. However you can also cheat. If you grab zero or more than three matches you instantly lose. I can't get my program to stop working after there is 1 match or someone cheats.

```
while (Matches > 1)
{
    

    
    cout << "Player 1 chooses 1 to 3 matches." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 to 3 matches: ";
    cin >> Matches1;
    
    if (Matches1<1 || Matches1>3)
    {
        cout << "Player 1 is cheating! << endl << Player 2 has won.";
    }
    
    Matches = Matches - Matches1;

    


    if (Lucifers <= 1)
    {
        cout << "Speler 1 heeft het spel verloren!";
        
    }

    cout << endl << "There are " << Matches << " matches left." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    
    cout << "Player 2 chooses 1 to 3 matches." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 to 3 matches: ";
    cin >> Matches2;

    if (Matches2 < 1 || Matches2 > 3)
    {
        cout << "Player 2 is cheating!" << endl << "Player 2 has won.";
    }

    Matches = Matches - Matches2;

    if (Matches <= 1)
    {
        cout << "Player 2 has lost!";
    }

    cout << endl << "There are " << Matches << " matches left." << endl;
    cout << endl;

}
```

I want the loop to end after cheating or after one of the players has lost

Comment: Why do you not want to use `break`, `exit()` or `return`?  Those are how you would solve your problem.

Comment: (Playing devil's advocate) If you don't want to use some "bad" ways, you can use some worse alternatives instead - call `std::terminate()`, use `goto end_of_program;`, or `throw "You lose!"`. Or maybe not...

Comment: Throw an exception.   If the caller doesn't catch it (which will be difficult to do without access to source code if documentation omits any mention of the type of exception being thrown ;-) ) then the program will terminate.

Comment: If your platform supports it, you can use inline assembly and execute the `hcf` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Add another condition to the loop and keep track of whether somebody cheated.
Use `else` to control the conditional flow.

Quick example:

```
bool cheating = false;
while (Matches > 1 && !cheating) {
    cout << endl << "There are " << Matches << " matches left." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Player 1 chooses 1 to 3 matches." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 to 3 matches: ";
    cin >> Matches1;
    if (Matches1<1 || Matches1>3) {
        cout << "Player 1 is cheating! << endl << Player 2 has won.";
        cheating = true;
    }
    else {
        Matches = Matches - Matches1;
        if (Matches <= 1) {
            cout << "Speler 1 heeft het spel verloren!";
        }
        else {
            cout << endl << "There are " << Matches << " matches left." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Player 2 chooses 1 to 3 matches." << endl;
            cout << "Enter 1 to 3 matches: ";
            cin >> Matches2;
            if (Matches2 < 1 || Matches2 > 3) {
                cout << "Player 2 is cheating!" << endl << "Player 2 has won.";
                cheating = true;
            }
            else {
                Matches = Matches - Matches2;
                if (Matches <= 1) {
                    cout << "Player 2 has lost!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but since you just repeat the procedure for each player, you can do one player per iteration and switch the player each time.
This simplifies the flow a lot.

Something like this (warning: untested)

```
std::string players[] = { "Player 1", "Player 2" };
int player = 0;
bool cheating = false;
while (Matches > 1 && !cheating) {
    cout << endl << "There are " << Matches << " matches left." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << players[player] << " chooses 1 to 3 matches." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 to 3 matches: ";
    int selection = 0;
    cin >> selection;
    cheating = selection < 1 || selection > 3;
    if (!cheating) {
        player = 1 - player;
        Matches = Matches - selection;
    }
}
if (cheating) {
    cout << players[player] << " cheated!" << endl;
}
cout << players[1-player] << " won the game!" << endl;
```

(I'm not entirely sure that I got the correct winning conditions.)

Answer (score -1):

Just call break, and while loop with exit

```
while (Matches > 1) {
... // stuff 
break;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/cpp/cpp/break-statement-cpp?view=msvc-160

Comment: The question title says *"without using exit(), return 0 or break"*